# proof of ratio of area of quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

In the convex quadrilateral ABCD, points M and N lie on AB such that AM =MN=NB.Points P and Q lie on side CD such that CP=PQ=QD.How can we prove that area of AMCP is 1/3 of ABCD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw diagonal AC. 
Show that area(AMC) = 1/3 area(ABC)
hint: think of AM and AB as the bases of the two triangles.
Do the same with CPA and CDA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am sorry i did not reply before.Was busy with fermat's lil theorem.